# Iterating array and creating multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For simplicity I have an array:

```
 Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [content] => Item One
        [type] => Breakfast
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [content] => Item Two
        [type] => Breakfast
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [content] => Item One
        [type] => Lunch
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [content] => Item One
        [type] => Dinner
    )
 )
```

What is the most efficient way to create a new multidimensional array where it would combine on matching key "type"?  Like below.  Current trying in a foreach.  Are there any built in functions for this?

```
 Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [content] => Item One
        [type] => Breakfast
    ),
    (
        [content] => Item Two
        [type] => Breakfast
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [content] => Item One
        [type] => Lunch
    ),
[2] => Array
    (
        [content] => Item One
        [type] => Dinner
    )
 )
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Well currently doing it with a foreach loop and checking type as I iterate over and if type has changed do something but its gotten really ugly.

Comment: Without showing us what you expect the output to be and without showing us what you've tried you're not likely to get an answer where someone will just produce the code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate through the input array and create a new output array. Take a look at this simple example:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'content' => 'Item One',
        'type' => 'Breakfast',
    ],
    [
        'content' => 'Item Two',
        'type' => 'Breakfast',
    ],
    [
        'content' => 'Item Three',
        'type' => 'Lunch',
    ],
    [
        'content' => 'Item Four',
        'type' => 'Dinner',
    ]
];
$output = [];

array_walk(
    $input,
    function($element) use (&$output) {
        $output[$element['type']][] = $element;
    }
);
print_r($output);
```

The output of above obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [Breakfast] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Item One
                    [type] => Breakfast
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Item Two
                    [type] => Breakfast
                )

        )

    [Lunch] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Item Three
                    [type] => Lunch
                )

        )

    [Dinner] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [content] => Item Four
                    [type] => Dinner
                )

        )

)
```

Of course you can place whatever element and structure you want inside the created array. For this example I just accepted the original elements, since that is irrelevant for demonstrating how to easily iterate through the array.

If you insist on a numeric key sequence in the output array, then you can simply use `print_r(array_values($output));` instead of `print_r($output)`...

Comment: Interesting... array_walk... never seen this one before.  takes an array, callback and userdata.  This is cool!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through it and push them in a new array by TYPE

e.g :

```
$newitmes = [];
 foreach($arr as $item){
    $type = $item['type'];
    $newitmes[$type][] = $item;
 }
print_r($newitmes);
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: It appears you did not test your own code... `$iem` != `$item` and the orthography in `$newitmes` is, well... "creative" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for noticing.